# How can i create button upload file in these scratch code

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

I want to add the file upload button in the following box, how will I do it, I'm also just starting with scratch source code, so I'm not very clear about the structure and how to code.

```
{
  opcode: "predictCho_Meo",
  blockType: BlockType.REPORTER,
  text: formatMessage({
    id: "dssama.chomeo",
    default: "Predict Cat And Dog: [paths]", //Flow id: [FLOW_ID]
    description: "",
  }),
  arguments: {
    // FLOW_ID: {
    //     type: ArgumentType.STRING,
    //     defaultValue: " ",
    // },
    paths: {
      type: ArgumentType.STRING,
      defaultValue: " ",
    },
  },
},
predictCho_Meo(args) {
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let id_flow_exist = searchParams.has("id_flow");
  if (!id_flow_exist) {
    return "Không tìm thấy flow ID";
  } else {
    let FLOW_ID = searchParams.get("id_flow");
    if (args.paths != " ") {
      //args.FLOW_ID && args.FLOW_ID != " " &&
      try {
        const reqData = {
          datasets: [{
            inputStageId: "",
            dataType: "image_clsf",
            class_names: [
              "Alaskan_Malamutes_Dog",
              "Bengal_Cat",
              "Pomeranians_Dog",
              "Poodles_Dog",
              "Siberian_Huskies_Dog",
            ],
            data: [{
              images: "",
              paths: args.paths,
              labels: "",
            }, ],
          }, ],
        };

        // TODO nhcuong Neu dung internal net => 192 else 118
        const response = request(
          "POST",
          `http://118.70.52.237:4813/released/runflow/${FLOW_ID}`, {
            json: reqData,
          }
        );
        const result = JSON.parse(response.getBody("utf8"));
        return result[0]["y_pred"];
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    } else {
      return "Tất cả đầu vào không được để trống";
    }
  }
}
```

There is a button to upload files in the empty box. Here is the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDNSd.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.